# Overloading operator== with `&&` and `const` qualifier cause ambiguity in C++20

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, comparison, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider the `struct` `S` with two `operator==` overloads of same `&&` qualifier and different `const` qualifier:

```
struct S {
  bool operator==(const S&) && { 
    return true;
  }
  bool operator==(const S&) const && { 
    return true;
  }
};
```

If I compare the two `S` with `operator==`:

```
S{} == S{};
```

gcc and msvc accept this code, clang [rejects](https://godbolt.org/z/66G6PTbc8) it with:

```
<source>:14:7: error: use of overloaded operator '==' is ambiguous (with operand types 'S' and 'S')
  S{} == S{};
  ~~~ ^  ~~~
```

Why does clang think there is an ambiguous overload resolution here? Shouldn't the non-const one be the best candidate in this case?

Similarly, if I compare two `S` with the synthesized `operator!=`:

```
S{} != S{};
```

gcc still accept this code, but msvc and clang [doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/qYb8v85P3):

```
<source>:14:7: error: use of overloaded operator '!=' is ambiguous (with operand types 'S' and 'S')
  S{} != S{};
  ~~~ ^  ~~~
```

It seems weird that the synthesized `operator!=` suddenly causes the ambiguity for msvc. Which compiler is right?

Comment: Candidates for `(S&&, S&&)` are `(S&&, const S&&)`, `(const S&&, const S&&)`, `(const S&&, S&&)/*rewritten*/`. each `S&&` is better match than `const S&&`, so call should be ambiguous IMO.

Comment: I also think Clang is correct, as @Jarod42 has pointed out. `S{}` is not const, but the expression `S{} == S{}` will need to choose between the best match, _argument per argument_, say `arg1` and `arg2`, among four synthesized overloads, and for `arg1` `(S&&, const S&&)` will be ambigious to `(S&&, S&&)` (and conversely for `arg2`). If we compare to when using function call notation (which Clang accepts), `S{}.operator(S{})`, the overload set will be `(const S&&, const S&)` and `(S&&, const S&)`, for which the latter is unambigiously a best match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example would be unambiguous in C++17. C++20 brings change:

> [over.match.oper]
>
> For a unary operator @ with an operand of type cv1 T1, and for a binary operator @ with a left operand of type cv1 T1 and a right operand of type cv2 T2, four sets of candidate functions, designated member candidates, non-member candidates, built-in candidates, **and rewritten candidates**, are constructed as follows:
>
> - ...
> - For the operator ,, the unary operator &, or the operator ->, the built-in candidates set is empty. **For all other operators, the built-in candidates include all of the candidate operator functions defined in [over.built] that, compared to the given operator,**
>
>   - have the same operator name, and
>   - accept the same number of operands, and
>   - accept operand types to which the given operand or operands can be converted according to [over.best.ics], and
>   - do not have the same parameter-type-list as any non-member candidate that is not a function template specialization.
>
> The rewritten candidate set is determined as follows:
>
> - ...
> - **For the equality operators, the rewritten candidates also include a synthesized candidate, with the order of the two parameters reversed**, for each non-rewritten candidate for the expression y == x.

Thus, the rewritten candidate set includes these:

```
 implicit object parameter
 |||
(S&&, const S&);       // 1
(const S&&, const S&); // 2

// candidates that match with reversed arguments
(const S&, S&&);       // 1 reversed
(const S&, const S&&); // 2 reversed
```

The overload 1 is better match than 2, but the synthesised reversed overload of 1 is ambiguous with the original non-reversed overload because both have const conversion to one parameter. Note that this is actually ambiguous even if overload 2 doesn't exist.

Thus, Clang is correct.

---

This is also covered by the informative compatibility annex:

> Affected subclause: [over.match.oper] Change: Equality and inequality expressions can now find reversed and rewritten candidates.
>
> Rationale: Improve consistency of equality with three-way comparison and make it easier to write the full complement of equality
> operations.
>
> Effect on original feature: Equality and inequality expressions between two objects of different types, where one is convertible to
> the other, could invoke a different operator. **Equality and inequality
> expressions between two objects of the same type could become
> ambiguous.**
>
> ```
> struct A {
>   operator int() const;
> };
>
> bool operator==(A, int);        // #1
> // #2 is built-in candidate: bool operator==(int, int);
> // #3 is built-in candidate: bool operator!=(int, int);
>
> int check(A x, A y) {
>   return (x == y) +             // ill-formed; previously well-formed
>     (10 == x) +                 // calls #1, previously selected #2
>     (10 != x);                  // calls #1, previously selected #3
> }
> ```

Comment: I'm a little confused. There seems to be issues with constness as well. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/hzKje36aW) is an example. Sometimes it warns about ambiguity, sometimes it errors and sometimes it's ok.

Comment: @Timo Constness is the issue in the OP's example. Your A is OK because both parameters are const. There cannot be synthesised reversed overload with same parameter list, so there is no ambiguity. B has differing constness like OP's example. It can be fixed by making the parameters the same type using const qualifier as you did in F. C is unambiguous like A except there are additional candidates that are unambiguously lower rank matches. D is ambiguous like B but with extra candidates like C. E isn't like D because there is no comparison operator for itself (likely copy paste error).

Comment: Whoops E was a copy paste error, yes. Ok got it now, thank you. One last question tho: why is B only a warning?

Comment: @Timo For definitive answer, you'll need to ask that from Clang authors. But I suspect that part of the reasoning is to make backwards incompatibility  "softer" by allowing previously well defined programs to continue working as a language extension.

Comment: Oh so it should be an error if it was standard conform?

Comment: @Timo No, standard doesn't require ill-formed programs to be errors. Diagnostic message is sufficient for standard conformance.

Comment: Let me rephrase: according to the C++20 standard the use of B in line 36 is ill-formed, correct?

Comment: @Timo Yes, the comparison / overload resolution is ill-formed. Clang is correct to diagnose the ill-formedness of the program. Other compilers that do not diagnose the issue do not conform to the standard.